# Koala fails to perform put_connections as a page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, koala

I have a ruby on rails app that uses Koala to integrate with facebook.
I use Put_connections to post a GraphAPI action and object to facebook. 
Share on wall works perfect using a line like this

```
 Thread.new {
   @graph.put_connections("me", "MyApp:MyAction", :MyObject=> url_for(@myobject), :image=> image_location)
}
```

also posting a simple message as the page works perfectly using

```
@page_graph.put_object('mypage-id', 'feed', :message => 'This is posted as the page 2')
```

However when i try to post the graphApi action as the page, nothing happens. using the following lines:

```
Thread.new {
@page_graph.put_connections('mypage-id', "MyApp:MyAction", :MyObject=> url_for(@myobject), :image=> image_location)
        }
```

any idea what might be the cause of this issue, or how can I debug this?
BTW, the app is hosted on Heroku and Heroku logs doesn't show any errors

Update:

I can successfully post the simple message with these lines as well:

```
@page_graph.put_connections('mypage-id', 'feed', :message => 'This is posted as the page 2')
```

Comment: Open Graph actions are meant to be undertaken by users, a.k.a. “real persons”. You _can not_ publish an action for a Facebook page.

Comment: @CBroe Thank you very much, it makes sense. what about any other way to post the Graph API object without the action?

Comment: You can always just post it as a link – then Facebook will extract all the OG meta data it uses for displaying links; but other, OG object specific data might not be used/displayed in the way you might want it to.

Comment: @CBroe Thanks, yes it appears that it is the only possible way